# Canonical Unicode string form

Tags: c++, c, unicode, collation, unicode-normalization

I have a Unicode string encoded, say, as `UTF8`. One string in Unicode can have few byte representations. I wonder, is there any or can be created any canonical (normalized) form of Unicode string -- so we can e.g. compare such strings with `memcmp(3)` etc. Can e.g. ICU or any other `C/C++` library do that?

Comment: Glib has [unicode manipulation](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.30/glib-Unicode-Manipulation.html) facility. [`g_utf8_collate`](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.30/glib-Unicode-Manipulation.html#g-utf8-collate) maybe?

Comment: http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/normalization

Comment: The question is too vague. Please define what you mean by “One string in Unicode can have few byte representations,” preferably illustrating it with examples. If the encoding is definitely UTF-8 and this is about a sequence of Unicode characters, then there is no such possibility.

Comment: @Jukka: If you write some string on the paper in some European language, with all those accents etc., you can have many unicode representations. And we would like to unify them.

Comment: @James, in that case, encodings (utf-8) are irrelevant, and the first question is how you define unification then. Do you consider canonical equivalence only, or also compatibility equivalence, or something else? What is the purpose of canonicalization here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might be looking for [Unicode normalisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_normalization). There are essentially four different normal forms that each ensure that all equivalent strings have a common form afterwards. However, in many instances you need to take locale into account as well, so while this may be a cheap way of doing a byte-to-byte comparison (if you ensure the same Unicode transformation format, like UTF-8 or UTF-16 and the same normal form) it won't gain you much apart from that limited use case.

Comment: Well, let's say that there are many more comparisons than the time needed to find-out canonical form of strings. Would you then consider normalisation as a good way?

Comment: Canonicalization is quite fast. Many codepoints don't change at all. The only hard part is whether you want to treat "Æ" as "AE".

Comment: MSalters: `Æ` has no decomposition mapping.

Answer (score 4):

Comparing Unicode codepoint sequences:

UTF-8 is a canonical representation itself. Two Unicode strings that are composed of the same Unicode codepoints will always be encoded to exactly the same UTF-8 byte sequence and thus can be compared with `memcmp`. It is a necessary property of the UTF-8 encoding, otherwise it would not be easily decodable. But we can go further, this is true for all official Unicode encoding schemes, UTF-8, UTF-16 and UTF-32. They encode a string to different byte sequences, but they always encode the same string to the same sequence. If you consider endianness and platform independence, UTF-8 is the recommended encoding scheme because you don't have to deal with byte orders when reading or writing 16-bit or 32-bit values.

So the answer is that if two strings are encoded with the *same encoding scheme* (eg. UTF-8) and endiannes (it's not an issue with UTF-8), the resulting byte sequence will be the same.

Comparing Unicode strings:

There's an other issue that is more difficult to handle. In Unicode some glyphs (the character you see on the screen or paper) can be represented with a single codepoint or a combination of two consecutive codepoints (called *combining characters*). This is usually true for glyphs with accents, diacritic marks, etc. Because of the different codepoint representation, their corresponding byte sequence will differ. Comparing strings while taking these combining characters into consideration can not be performed with simple byte comparison, first you have to normalize it.

The other answers mention some Unicode normalization techniques, canonical forms and libraries that you can use for converting Unicode strings to their normal form. Then you will be able to compare them byte-by-byte with any encoding scheme.

Comment: To expand on the comments about combining characters, to compare such strings you 'normalize' the string of codepoints. Look for Composed Normalization Form (NFC) or Decomposed Normalization Form (NFD). There are also compatibility normalization forms NFCK and NFDK. However there's still more to comparing strings. For example if you want to ignore case in languages that have that you do case folding, and other languages have other things you need to consider.

Comment: While this sounds reasonable, it's not how Unicode is actually specified. UTF-8 is a canonical representation of codepoints, yes, but the question was about strings. Your PS. is not a postscriptum, but the core problem in locale-independent string comparisons. (Locale-dependent and/or case-insensitive string comparisons are yet another matter, but probably irrelevant here - the question already mentioned `memcmp`.)

Comment: You're both right. It seems I misunderstood that part of the question.

Comment: @MSalters: Nice comment! So, how can we deal with the fact that one "string on paper" (e.g. in some European language) can have many unicode byte representations and we should all of them consider equal? Is there any "unification"?

Comment: @James: See Joey's answer, that's why I didn't add another answer. If two strings are binary equal after normalization, then you should consider them equal.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking to normalize the string to one of the Unicode normalization forms. libicu can do this for you, but not on a UTF-8 string. You have to first convert it to UChar, using e.g. `ucnv_toUChars`, then normalize with `unorm_normalize`, then convert back using `ucnv_fromUChars`. I think there's also some specific version of ucnv_* for UTF-8 encoding.

If memcmp is your only goal you can of course do that directly on the UChar array after `unorm_normalize`.

Comment: It's a libicu function. http://www.icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/unorm_8h.html#a5410fab40c4e60a787c5cfbea5103c75